# Let A be an array of n positive integers, It's known that the highest number in the array is k=n^5. Find the best possible sorting

Tags: sorting

I got the next question in a quiz:

Let A be an array of n positive integers, It's known that the highest number in the array is k=n^5. Find the best possible sorting of the algorithm.

My answer was: Since i know the highest number (And the amount of its digits), Firstly i'll find the amount of it's digits, then I'll use radix sort.

The official answer was: Radix sort, With n as a base, and d=6.

I can't understand why? why d=6? why choosing n as base? Thanks.
'

Comment: I think the question/official answer is somewhat flawed. It depends on what you mean by "best possible", but for smallish n I'd expect simple sorting methods like quicksort would beat the radix sort. For large n, it will depend on the distribution of data: if it's already nearly sorted then timsort might win, for example....

Comment: That official answer completely ignores the fact that base conversion may be an expensive operation or that when using real computers it is usually better to stick to the bases they support natively (i.e., 2**8, 2**16, 2**32 or 2**64).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because n^5 is 1 followed by 5 zeroes in base n:

- If n=10, 10^5 = 10000.
- If n=2, 2^5 = 32 = 10000 in binary.

Comment: How does it fit in with the radix sort? I mean, lets take n=2, Array[11,31]. As i see it, Radix sort goes through the least significant digit, Sorts it according to the given base, And for both 11 and 31 i should get the same thing [1 for the LSD, and 1 for the one after it] or i just don't understand radix sort.

Comment: You're radix-sorting on base n, so if n=1, your array is [01011, 01111], and you perform radix sort by ordering over each bit. (That is, for the first step, both have a 1 in position 0; for the second step, both have a 1; for the third step, 11 has a 0 but 31 has a 1; and so on.)